# Firebase Cloud Function and multiple requests

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the code below to run a function to create a set of documents, when there is a single request on this cloud function, it works fine.

When I make multiple requests upon this function in quick succession, the function fails.

Does anyone have anything they can suggest?

```
export const importCaseCreateCaseStatus = functions.firestore.
 document('caseStatus/{case}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

 const caseReference = snap.id;
 console.log(caseReference)

 var reg = "[^£]*£[^£]*";
 const uid = caseReference.match(reg);
 if (uid) {

 let ref = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("0")
 let ref1 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("1")
 let ref2 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("2")
 let ref3 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("3")
 let ref4 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("4")
 let ref5 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("5")
 let ref6 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("6")
 let ref7 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("7")
 let ref8 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("8")
 let ref9 = db.collection('caseStatus').doc(caseReference).collection("0").doc("9")

 batch.set(ref, arrayMilestones[0]);
 batch.set(ref1, arrayMilestones[1]);
 batch.set(ref2, arrayMilestones[2]);
 batch.set(ref3, arrayMilestones[3]);
 batch.set(ref4, arrayMilestones[4]);
 batch.set(ref5, arrayMilestones[5]);
 batch.set(ref6, arrayMilestones[6]);
 batch.set(ref7, arrayMilestones[7]);
 batch.set(ref8, arrayMilestones[8]);
 batch.set(ref9, arrayMilestones[9]);

 return batch.commit().then(function () {
 console.log("imported milestones")
 return null

 });
 }

 });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include enough information so that anyone can reproduce the failure.  The question should contain error messages and the exact steps to reproduce.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: writeBatch error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is related with your code, seems more related how you can manage the Cloud Functions service.

Cloud functions will automatically scale up when it determines that more capacity is needed. The instances will be scaled down when they are no longer needed.

I recommend you take a look at this document where you can find useful information about how to use Pub/Sub triggers on Cloud Functions,  Pub/Sub is a globally distributed message bus that automatically scales as you need it [1].

Also I suggest you check these videos where is explained how works the function scaling [2] and how to deal with parallel execution [3].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

[2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCpKxpIMg6o

[3] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzTS6mFDGjU